# Which of these sentences are correct

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it correct to say

> When do we going to bike

or

> When are we going to ride a bicycle /when we go to ride bicycle

or can I use either?

Comment: The first one is incorrect. _When are we going to bike_ would be correct. the last one too: _When do we go ride a bicycle_ would be correct. The middle one is correct

Comment: Syntactically, auxiliary "do" is never followed by the "-ing" form,  but by the base (or infinitive). So "do we going" is never grammatical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is incorrect.

> When are we going to bike

would be correct.

The last one is also incorrect.

> When do we go ride a bicycle

would be correct.

The middle one is correct.

> When are we going to ride a bicycle

Here is a good `ing` tutorial: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-ing-clauses

Comment: Is bike a verb in BrE or some other dialect, then? In AmE, "to bike" would not be correct. There's no real one-word substitute for "to ride a bike."

Comment: I'm going to bike up the mountain Saturday.

Comment: Where in the US are you from @joiedevivre ? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+bike&year_start=1960&year_end=2017&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20bike%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bike via collinsdict

Comment: Utah. I've never heard "to bike" but I wholeheartedly support its becoming a verb! Thanks for the links. :)